# one third container leaving white space at end css

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem on a website i am building:

3 columns of equal height and 1/3 width but on the last column there is a small white gap on the right hand side.  I cant figure out why, here is what I'm talking about:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V36dA.png)

See the white line by the right hand side of the blog image.

The code I'm am using for the 1/3rd column is:

```
.thirdBox {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 20px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 400px;
  display: table;
}
```

and the background images:

```
.thirdBox:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: url("imagelinkhere...") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let's say your window width is 100px ... So each column will be 33.33px which will sum up to 99.99px and not 100px.. Hence the gap

Comment: What is the best way to get rid of that gap reddy?

Comment: You can try to use `%` instead of `px`

Comment: compromise with the width i guess,use 34% for the left and right div's and 32% for the middle div,or you can go for 33.5% for the left and right one.

Comment: @RickyD may be the answer below will help.. Let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that 100%/3 is 33.33% in most browsers, not quite the exact width you want it to be.

Instead of using `calc()` to find each table's width, I would use `display:flex;` on the parent of all three elements you want to be in one row.

This is the best I can help you with without any HTML structure. Please post that and I may be able to help you more.

```css
.parentElement{
  display:flex;
}

.firstBox, .secondBox, .thirdBox {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  flex:1;
}

.firstBox{
  background:blue;  
}

.secondBox{
  background:red;  
}

.thirdBox{
  background:green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parentElement">
  <div class="firstBox"></div>
  <div class="secondBox"></div>
  <div class="thirdBox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using `display: table`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
            <span>Menu</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
            <p>Some text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
            <span>Blog</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.row {
    background-color: #999; 
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.col-inner {
    display: table;
  width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}

.col:first-child,
.col:last-child {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.col-inner span,
.col-inner p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```